# Adding a condition to if statement if another condition is true

Tags: java

Is it possible to add a condition in if statement if a certain condition is true?

For example,

I have this variable,
`private Boolean doesExist`

if `doesExist` is set to `True` then I want my if statement like this,

`if (A == B && B == C)`

if `doesExist` is set to `False` then I don't want the second condition in my if condition,

`if (A == B)`

Comment: doesExist ? (A == B && B == C) : (A == B)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
if ((doesExist && (A == B && B == C)) || (!doesExist && A == B)) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

When `doesExist` is true, the predicate depends on `(A == B && B == C)` (left side of the 'or' operator); when `doesExist` is false, the predicate depends on `A == B` (right side of 'or' operator.

Even more sucinct, what about:

```
if(A == B && (!doesExist || B == C)) {
    // do stuff
}
```

In this case, the value of `B == C` only affects the overall value of the predicate when `doesExist` is `True`.

Comment: while not the shortest, it's the most understandable, and this has value as Ron26 is a new member. Well done

Answer (score 0):

You can just go with

```
if(doesExist ? (A == B && B == C) : (A == B))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
if (A == B && (!doesExist || B == C))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the A == B condition will change, then we need update it in two places in suggested solutions, I think better would be to always test A == B and conditionally test second one like:

`if(A == B && (!test || B == C))`